# Hookup Nest Themostat & Heatlink

Tags: hot-water, central-heating, nest

I'm in the UK and trying to install a Nest Thermostat & Heatlink at home to control my hot-water and central heating and I'm having a few issues working out how my existing setup works so I can swap it out.

My heating controller is currently wired as the below which does not seem to match any of the examples in Nests installation guide.
[image: Current Wiring Diagram]

My temperature thermostat has the below connections:
[image: Current theromstat wiring]

*Earth's excluded from diagrams for clarity*

From this I believe the Multicore 2 goes to there thermostat but I'm not 100% sure (I plan to bell this out this weekend with my multimeter). If it is I'm not sure why it would only have 2 wires connectioned at the controller end (Red of Multicore 2 goes nowhere)

I have a Conventional Boiler, which looking at the Nest Installation Guide https://nest.com/support/images/misc-nest-thermostat-eu/gen3-install/3rd-gen-Nest-Learning-Thermostat-Install-Guide-UK.pdf I belive must be a S-Plan or a Y-Plan.

Can anyone offer any guidance on how I figure this out? I'm more used to industrial cabinet wiring where everything is labeled so I'm finding this a wee bit tricky.

First time posting to this stack so please let me know if theres any info I've missed.

Comment: Just in case anyone stumbles across this and is curious . In the end i commoned the Live to the Call in the thermostat box (L to 3) and put a plate over the hole. I then connected the calls for Hot Water and Central Heating that had been going into the control to the same in the nest Heat Link (the Heatlink also requires a common live for those signals). I just set up the nest thermostat to work on wireless.